# A good website builder that I can save / export as HTML? (Bootstrap?)

Tags: html, web, builder

I used wix to create a site, then I downloaded it from my browser and removed the ads, but now the embedded youtube videos dont work. I basically want to start from scratch and create a website like [this](http://chace.comuf.com/chace.htm), but with working embeds...

My problem is that the youtube videos are not playing in my [modified wix files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tbb1bzcus5gk9dq/chace%20files%202.zip?dl=0). I either need to get those working or start from scratch.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: you could view the page source for that page and then copy the parts you want

Comment: The only problem is that the embeds arnt working.

Comment: Lexi, thanks for letting me know, I added the problem.

Comment: Ah, I found webflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all you need to do is, Look at the page source and find the `<iframe></iframe>`containing the unplayable YouTube video.  Replace it with an iframe from "YouTube.com" for example [YouTube image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5amQ.png)
JS-fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/Lp3h60m0/

Comment: Thanks. Ill try it.

Comment: Would those iframes be in chace.htm (index.html)?

Comment: Wow it worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: you are very welcome my friend